# How to define a common serializer with nesting for both create and view operations in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have these models.

```
class Salon(models.Model):
    salon_name= models.CharField(max_length=250,null=False,blank=False,unique=True)
    ...

class Review(models.Model):
    salon = models.ForeignKey(Salon,null=False,blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=False,blank=False)
    ...
```

I have defined the serializers as below.

```
class SalonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Salon
        fields = ('id', 'salon_name', 'address_line1', 'land_mark', 'area', 
              'price_range', 'email_id', 'is_mail_id_verified', 
              'salon_type', 'rating', 'parking_available', 'latitude', 
              'longitude')

class ReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    salon = SalonSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('id', 'salon', 'stylist', 'rating', 'review_text', 'user')
```

I am using the same review serializer for ListAPIView, CreateAPIView and UpdateAPIView. While creation and updation the request is expecting the complete dictionary of Salon whereas it is just a foreign key.

Please suggest if there is any work around or how to model such cases.

Comment: "While creation and updation the request is expecting the complete dictionary of Salon whereas it is just a foreign key" Do you mean that you want create and update to be a primary key, but listing/detail should be the nested serializer? Your question doesn't make this particularly clear. If you can also provide information on what you have already tried, that would be helpful.

Comment: Yes @kevin-brown, I want create and update to be a primary key but listing/detail should be using nested serializer.

Comment: @kevin-brown We have tried to use a different serializer for listing/detail. But we are looking for some nice way which is built in DRF.